# Rewrite old image urls to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I had some images that were in the root folder of the website, and they are linked from another website using `<img src="" />`

after the redesign things changed and now the images are in a new folder called imgs

So what I need is somehow the old urls to work but serve the image from another folder.

```
http://example.com/file.JPG should be served from http://example.com/imgs/file.JPG
```

I've tried this but doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.JPG$ /imgs/$1\.JPG [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.jpe?g)$ /imgs/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```